# You have to have "something"

Tags: grammar

I have a question. I was trying to find out if it's correct to say "you have to have", but I couldn't find an answer...I think people would normally use "you should have"  or "you must have". In a guessing game, there weren't many options left, so in a hurry I used "have to have". Is it entirely wrong?

I'd really, really like to know the answer, in order to use proper grammar in the future.

Thank you very much. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly okay to say

> In order to be a passably decent person you *have to have* a conscience.

Comment: I think OP is asking about, “You have to have seen it, it was right in front of you.”